# Mutiple request is generated in single click in Jmeter

Tags: java, request, jmeter, response

I am trying to Script via Jmeter. Earlier in all application on which I have done scripting , only one relevant request was generated, and having that one req in jmeter, retrieved all information on that page to proceed with further requests.

But now in this application, when I am recording using Jmeter, After a single click, multiple request is generated in jmeter scripts (like 3 to 10) and none one alone is having total response when ran via jemter.

1. What kind of application is this? And what is advantage of doing in this way?
2. How can I handle this in most effient way?

For Eg on one click below are request generated in HTTP recorder in jmeter.

```
http://xxxx:9081/vam-ui
http://xxx:9081/vam-rest/common/getAPIAddresses
http://xxx:9081/vam-rest/authenticate
http://xxx:9081/vam-rest/getuserinfo
68 /AASWeb/rest/aas/v1/authentication/authenticateUser
69 /AASWeb/rest/aas/v1/authentication/authenticateUser
70 /AASWeb/rest/aas/v1/authentication/getUserProfile
71 /AASWeb/rest/aas/v1/authentication/getUserProfile
73 /AASWeb/rest/aas/v1/authorization/getUserUIAuthorization
74 /AASWeb/rest/aas/v1/authorization/getUserUIAuthorization
75 /AccountWeb/rest/account/v1/operation/getSystemDate
76 /CustomerWeb/rest/customer/v1/customer/searchRootCustomers
77 /AccountWeb/rest/account/v1/account/searchAccountsService
80 /AccountWeb/rest/account/v1/operation/getSystemDate
78 /uiframework-web/api/rest/dashboard/v1/listAvailableDashboards
79 /uiframework-web/api/rest/dashboard/v1/getUserRecentSearches
82 /CustomerWeb/rest/customer/v1/customer/searchRootCustomers
83 /uiframework-web/api/rest/dashboard/v1/listAvailableDashboards
84 /uiframework-web/api/rest/dashboard/v1/getUserRecentSearches
85 /uiframework-web/api/rest/dashboard/v1/listAvailableDashboards
86 /uiframework-web/api/rest/dashboard/v1/getUserRecentSearches
88 /uiframework-web/api/rest/dashboard/v1/listAvailableDashboards
89 /uiframework-web/api/rest/dashboard/v1/getUserRecentSearches
```

Comment: For eg: On one click, below are the request generated in Jmeter recorder:

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of replaying your scenario would be:

- [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) - to measure the cumulative execution time

  - HTTP Request sampler (main call)
  - [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter) - to execute all "nested" calls simultaneously

    - HTTP Request 1
    - HTTP Request 2
    - HTTP Request 3
    - ...